# Make a function wait until another send return

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function called "myCall()" like this:

```
function myCall() {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'file.php?id=10',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,       
        success: function(data) {
            return data;
        },
        error: function(data) {
            alert('error!');
        }
    });

}
```

As you can see, this funcion call the "file.php?id=10" and get a return.

That's ok.

But here is my localFunction():

```
function localFunction() {
    show = myCall();
    alert(show);
}
```

As you can see, the localFunction() alert shows "undefined".

How can I make the show = myCall() wait the response before go to next code line?

Fiddle:

Comment: "How can I make it wait" - you can't. What you _can_ do is run your alert in success handler of the ajax call.

Comment: Sergio is correct. You can pass your success function's "data" to another function if you are wanting to segregate.

Comment: @LukeBecker Chaining `.done` handlers could also work. But it hardly can be classified as "caller function waits for this to return"